# Where to place the AsyncTask() so that i can call it to load image?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Below is my coding where it would load the image when this Activity is called. But i wished to display the progressDialog when it was retrieving the images from the server instead of just a black screen presented to the user. I heard that AsyncTask is able to do but i stuck with where to place the AsyncTask function and calling it.

```
public class LargeImageScroller extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }

    private static class SampleView extends View {
        private static Bitmap bmLargeImage; //bitmap large enough to be scrolled
        private static Rect displayRect = null; //rect we display to
        private Rect scrollRect = null; //rect we scroll over our bitmap with
        private int scrollRectX = 0; //current left location of scroll rect
        private int scrollRectY = 0; //current top location of scroll rect
        private float scrollByX = 0; //x amount to scroll by
        private float scrollByY = 0; //y amount to scroll by
        private float startX = 0; //track x from one ACTION_MOVE to the next
        private float startY = 0; //track y from one ACTION_MOVE to the next

        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            displayRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

            scrollRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

            bmLargeImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(1035 , 665, Config.ARGB_8888);             
            bmLargeImage = createMap(this.getContext());

        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {....}

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {....}

        private static Bitmap createMap(Context context) {...}          

        private static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {....}

        private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int requiredSize) {...}

    }
}
```

I wish to know where should i place the AsyncTask function so as to display the progressDialog while the program is loading the image from server/cache. Most of the source i found on the internet doesn't say much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is somehow like a Thread. It is used to handle some time-consuming operations so that the main thread won't be blocked.
In your case, AsyncTask is suitable. However, the place where you would like to put it depends on your logic.

Please read the SDK: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to get more info about it. There is also a code snippet that may help you.

Added:

Well, I understand your concern. If you just want to show a progress bar to tell the users that the app is downloading the images from the server. You may handle this way:
1. Create a xml layout file containing a ProgressBar.
2. In OnCreate in Class LargeImageScroller, call `setContentView(R.layout.that_layout)` to show the progressbar, and Start a AsyncTask to download the images.
3.Inside AsyncTask, override `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` to tell the ProgressBar the donwloading progress.
4.  Inside AsyncTask, override `onPostExecute(Long result)`. This method will be called when the AsyncTask finishes. Here you can do : S`ampleView sv=new SampleView(this)`, and then pass the images to the sv object. Then  call `setContentView(sv)` to show your images.

This is just my train of thought. I think you can use AsyncTask in either LargeImageScroller class or SampleView class. Hope ithis comment helps.

Comment: as you can see in the code, i calling SampleView class to display the image and thats when i not sure where to including the class for the AsyncTask. Should i include in the entire LargeImageScroller class, outside LargeImageScroller class, inside SampleView class.

Comment: Well, I understand your concern. If you just want to show a progress bar to tell the users that the app is downloading the images from the server. You may handle this way :